# Retrieving actual return code of a Powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, salt-stack

I am trying to get a return code from a Powershell cmdlet. This return code will be passed to a Saltstack `cmd.run` state (*success_retcodes* [parameter](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run))

My cmdlet that should produce an error:`Get-PSSessionConfiguration test`

This will produce an error because *test* session does not exist.
Running `$?` right after always produces `True` whether the above cmdlet fails or not.

The purpose of this exercise is purposely not fail one of my states in Saltstack via the aforementioned parameter which I believe takes a numeral value.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the good ol' try/catch block?

```
Try {
    Get-PSSessionConfiguration test -ErrorAction stop
    return $true
} Catch {
    return $false
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I am trying to get the raw error code without changing it to something else

Comment: If you want just the error then you can either throw the error or write it as output - 'throw $_' or '$_'  - in case you would like to process the error first, grab the error type for example you could either do it within the catch block - or just assign the error into a variable and then process it from there.

```
[...]
catch {
 throw $_
}
```
or
```
$errorvar = $_
```

And then process the errorvar to your liking, or just leave the '$errorvar=' out - leaving you with just the whole text of error output.

Answer (score 1):

`$LASTEXITCODE` returns the last exit code. Or, `$Error` is where all errors are stored. From there you can filter what error you'd like to catch.

```
$Error | Select Exception
```

Comment: Thanks for this. $Error provides with the actual error messages as opposed to an error code right? I tried to dig the entries and couldn't find what I need. As far as I ca recall $lastexitcode only capture error codes from external command, not Powershell cmdlets. That is why I was quick to check the $? global variable.